# Difference of `conda deactivate` and simply closing the Conda terminal

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, conda

Sometimes I use the command `conda deactivate` (on windows) to deactivate the conda environment, but sometimes I forget it and directly close the Conda terminal. Does closing terminal directly may have some bad effects on the Conda environment?

Answer (score 4):

You probably shouldn't be using conda deactivate at all (it's primarily used for cleaning up and removing an environment, or for undoing nested activation).

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#deactivating-an-environment

> To simply return to the base environment, it's better to call conda activate with no environment specified, rather than to try to deactivate. If you run conda deactivate from your base environment, you may lose the ability to run conda at all. Don't worry, that's local to this shell - you can start a new one. However, if the environment was activated using --stack (or was automatically stacked) then it is better to use conda deactivate.

There's no harm in simply closing the terminal window.

Comment: I suspect some of the language here in the docs is artifactual: it comes from when `conda (de|)activate` functionality was first introduced and so the devs were perhaps being overcautious. In the 2+ years since Conda v4.4, I've never experienced a loss of Conda functionality from deactivating out of **base**. Nevertheless, I think the general sentiment is correct: it doesn't really matter whether one uses it or not, except for those with env stacking enabled (experimental and not a default). And even then, if you're exiting the shell it doesn't matter.

Comment: @merv Agreed. Main takeaway, in all these cases, is that if you somehow get stuck or also if you want to leave the prompt then simply exit the shell, and when you open up again things will be reinitialized to the base environment/config.